# Pass values from model to second one

Tags: c#, model

I have two models:

```
public class StatisticsModel
{
    public int? ProgressToBackCheck { get; set; }
    public int? BackcheckToCorrection { get; set; }
    public int? CorrectionsToCompleted { get; set; }
    public int? ProgressToCompleted { get; set; }
}

public class AssignStatisticsModel
{
    public string TasksName { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
}
```

I add info to second model as:

```
 List<AssignStatisticsModel> textModels = new List<AssignStatisticsModel>();
 AssignStatisticsModel textmodel = new AssignStatisticsModel();
        textmodel.TasksName = "Progress to Back Check";
           textModels.Add(textmodel);
        textmodel.TasksName = "Back Check to Corrections";
           textModels.Add(textmodel);
        textmodel.TasksName = "Corrections to Completed";
           textModels.Add(textmodel);
        textmodel.TasksName = "Progress to Completed";
           textModels.Add(textmodel);
```

so as you can see I have 4 rows but column `Time` is null, I want to fill it with information of my StatisticsModel:

```
List<StatisticsModel> models = new List<StatisticsModel>();

foreach (var i in tasks)
{
    StatisticsModel model = new StatisticsModel();

    var timeOfTasks = db.GetTableBySQL($"exec usp_Get_WorkedProyectTime @TaskTypeCategoryId = '{i.TaskTypeCategoryId}', @TaskId= '{i.TaskId}'");

    var progressToBackCheck = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows where timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("ProgressToBackCheck") select dr["ProgressToBackCheck"]).FirstOrDefault();
    var backCheckToCorrections = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows  where timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("BackCheckToCorrections") select dr["BackCheckToCorrections"]).FirstOrDefault();
    var correctionsToCompleted = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows where timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("CorrectionsToCompleted") select dr["CorrectionsToCompleted"]).FirstOrDefault();
    var progressToCompleted = (from DataRow dr in timeOfTasks.Rows  where timeOfTasks.Columns.Contains("ProgressToCompleted") select dr["ProgressToCompleted"]).FirstOrDefault();

    model.ProgressToBackCheck = (int?)progressToBackCheck;
    model.BackcheckToCorrection = (int?)backCheckToCorrections;
    model.CorrectionsToCompleted = (int?)correctionsToCompleted;
    model.ProgressToCompleted = (int?)progressToCompleted;

    models.Add(model);
}

StatisticsModel masterSet = models[0];
StatisticsModel leadLog = models[1];
StatisticsModel takeOff = models[2];
StatisticsModel consolidation = models[3];
StatisticsModel design = models[4];
StatisticsModel agreement = models[5];
StatisticsModel shops = models[6];
StatisticsModel hardSpec = models[7];
```

So as you can see I have 4 rows there too like in `masterSet` or leadLog . I want to know how can I get them and add into my AssignStatisticsModel column `Time`, is it possible to do some merge with `StatisticsModel` and pass values to  AssignStatisticsModel? Regards

I try to assign them into foreach like:

```
foreach (StatisticsModel m in masterSet)
{

}
```

But I get

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'StatisticsModel' because 'StatisticsModel' does not contain a public
>   instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

To be clear I put an example

**masterSet values**

[image]

**Current AssignStatisticsModel**

[image]

So that I want is to get value `ProgressToBackCheck` of `masterset` and pass to time[0] of `AssignStatisticsModel`, get value `BackcheckToCorrection`  of `masterset` and pass to time[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D6wF.png) of `AssignStatisticsModel` and etcetera

I try something like this:

```
foreach (var t in textModels)
            {
                if(t.TasksName.Equals("Progress to Back Check"))
                {
                    textmodel.Time = (int)masterSet.ProgressToBackCheck;
                    textModels.Add(textmodel);
                }
                if(t.TasksName.Equals("Back Check to Corrections"))
                {
                    textmodel.Time = (int)masterSet.BackcheckToCorrection;
                    textModels.Add(textmodel);
                }
                if (t.TasksName.Equals("Corrections to Completed"))
                {
                    textmodel.Time = (int)masterSet.CorrectionsToCompleted;
                    textModels.Add(textmodel);
                }
                if (t.TasksName.Equals("Progress to Completed"))
                {
                    textmodel.Time = (int)masterSet.ProgressToCompleted;
                    textModels.Add(textmodel);
                }
            }
```

But it changes all object into model and in the second round of foreach it returns:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified;
>   enumeration operation may not execute.'

Comment: Shouldn't you be `foreach`ing over `models` (as that is a collection) rather than `masterSet`, which is an instance of `StatisticsModel`?

Comment: I don't understand what you trying to say me, can you explain with a simple example @BrendanGreen

Comment: I'm failing to understand where and how you want to use `AssignStatisticsModel`.  Can you update your questions and put some pseudo code inside the `foreach` detailing what you want to do?

Comment: That I want to do is to get items that are in my `masterSet` and add into `AssignStatisticsModel` column `Time`, so that's why I try foreach because I want to assignate inside it something like: `textmodel.Time = m.column` and at the final just add `textModels.Add(textmodel);` let me update my question with some example data @BrendanGreen

Comment: Also please try and update the code fully.  The `textModel` isn't apparent in the main code fragment - we probably need to see how they are related

Comment: I update it, I update `textModel` too @BrendanGreen